# App Engine Jruby DataMapper List Property

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, jruby, datamapper

How to use list/array as property in DataMapper on Jruby on Google AppEngine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work like has..and..belongs..to..many, without a join table...

```
class Person
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,          Serial
  property :name,        String, :nullable => false
  property :project_ids, List
  timestamps :at
  # project should be flagged as archived, not deleted
  def projects
    Project.all(:id => project_ids)
  end
end

class Project
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,          Serial
  property :name,        String, :nullable => false
  property :archived,    Boolean, :default => false
  # the join table is bolted onto the person model
  def people
    Person.all(:project_ids => id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on the different ways to approach modeling with JRuby on App-Engine?